# Basic concatenation in Powershell doesn't work

Tags: powershell

I cannot push to $filepaths, can't see why :

```
$filepaths=@()
$files= @('file1.text','file2.txt')
foreach ($file in $files) {
  $filepaths.add("c:\test\" + $file)
}
$filepaths
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@()` is a [`System.Array`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array?view=net-6.0) (a **fixed collection**), reading from [**Remarks**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.system-collections-ilist-add?view=net-6.0#remarks) on the [`.Add` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.system-collections-ilist-add?view=net-6.0#system-array-system-collections-ilist-add(system-object)) from this Class:

> Ordinarily, an [`IList.Add`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ilist.add?view=net-6.0) implementation adds a member to a collection. However, because arrays have a fixed size (the [IsFixedSize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.isfixedsize?view=net-6.0) property always returns true), this method always throws a [NotSupportedException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.notsupportedexception?view=net-6.0) exception.

PowerShell offers us the ability to **recreate** the array **with a new element** using the [`+=` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays?view=powershell-7.2#manipulating-an-array), however this is **not recommended** for reasons very well explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60708578/why-should-i-avoid-using-the-increase-assignment-operator-to-create-a-colle).

You can either assign to a variable the output of your enumeration:

```sh
$filepaths = foreach($file in 'file1.txt', 'file2.txt') {
    "c:\test\" + $file
}
$filepaths
```

In this example, PowerShell will dynamically assign the type for `$filepaths`, if 1 element is returned from the enumeration it would be *string*, for more than one it would become `object[]` (`Array`).

Or use a collection that allows adding new elements, such as [`ArrayList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist?view=net-6.0) or [`List<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=net-6.0):

```sh
$filepaths = [Collections.Generic.List[string]]::new()
foreach($file in 'file1.txt', 'file2.txt') {
    $filepaths.Add("c:\test\" + $file)
}
$filepaths
```

Here, `$filepaths` would always be of the type `` List`1 ``.